# How to load plugin when I set up in profiles file without declarating the project dependencies in lein

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen

I want to use the lein plugin function in all projects when I start up the `lein repl`.

I want to call the function by sending the function to cider repl in emacs.

But I do not want to declare it in `lein project` file.

For example,

There is a lein plugin called `plugin-test`, and define a function

```
(defproject plugin-test "0.1.0")


(defn p-test[]
    (println "...."))
```

I add the plugin in `~/.lein/profiles.clj` file. 
Then I jump to my lein project dir and run `lein repl`

Now, how can I load `plugin-test` and call the function `p-test` ?

Comment: Why do you not want to put the plugin into your project.clj? I think you may be confused regarding lein, repl and projects. for example, defproject is part of the lein ecosystem. It is not part of clojure. Think of lein as a clojure application which helps you manage clojure projects.